How to trigger Keyboard events on opening of Dropdown list in Angular
Requirement-
On opening of dropdown menu, if we press delete key from keyboard then index should reset to -1.
Scenario to replicate the issue-
1.Click on dropdown, choose any option from the dropdown menu.
2.Again click on the dropdown, menu will get open , just click delete key from the keyboard.
3.Currently keydown/keyup event is not getting triggered on press if delete key.
Expectation- keydown event should get triggered on press of delete key when dropdown menu is in open state.
Kindly help me with your suggestion on how to call keyboard event when dropdown is open.
stackblitz

can you give more clarifications to the question , like what should be done when the delete is pressed , all i see is 3 option dropdown here,

Hi , The issue is when we select any option and focus is on dropdown and press delete key from keyboard it should get cleared.

ok, for that you have to give a default option and it should be selected, i give try and help you with a example.

Problem is when dropdown menu is open and we press delete key , keydown event is not getting trigger, whereas when we choose  an option and dropdown menu is closed , then press delete key from keyboard, then event is getting triggered

In one line it is like when focus is on dropdown list and it is open, no keyboard event gets triggered. How to resolve this

this is a simple solution of the problem link
here the select is binded with a ngModel and keyup event is checked for delete or backspace event then it is selecting for default value.
html
<select #myDropdown [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
 <option value="0">Select Option</option>
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

and in ts file
export class AppComponent {
name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
selectedValue = 0;
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
const dropdownElement =
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#myDropdown');
}

onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
if (event.key === 'Delete' || event.key === 'Backspace') {
  // Your deletion logic here
  // For example, select the next item in the list:
  this.selectedValue = 0;
}
}
}

Hope this help :)

Thank you , i tried the same but it is not working when delete key is pressed when dropdown is open.

Scenario to test- 1. Choose option1, 2. Again open select menu and press delete key when menu is open. It should reset to empty.
